# Como eu posso definir o padrão de hora como UTC ou GMT no PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Vários sistemas, sites grandes quando se é possível informar o horário eles pedem a escolha de UTC ou GMT. Já tentei fazer isso no PHP, mas não obtive sucesso utilizando o `default_date_timezone_set()`, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Sim é possível com o `default_date_timezone_set()`, qual time vc pega? sem sucesso significa o que exatamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode-se usar [`date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

[Coordinated Univeral Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) é a mesma coisa que [Greenwich Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time), mas hoje UTC subjetivamente é considerado mais correto no meio científico, sei lá porque. Pra computação dá na mesma, mas é mais moderno usar UTC.

Como é conceitual não há melhor, mais rápido, nada disto. Entenda que UTC é uma medida referencial. O GMT é considerado um fuso horário como outro qualquer que se confunde com o UTC. Em Londres/UK o GMT é usado a maior parte do ano como fuso oficial (mas não todo o tempo por causa o horário de verão).

[Mais informações aqui](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) e [aqui](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html).

Comment: Eu não ia responder esta, mas o AP removeu a outra pergunta que eu estava respondendo e não quis perder a resposta já pronta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124120/utc-e-gmt-há-diferença-entre-eles-ganho-vantagem-na-utilização-de-um-e-outro

Comment: Perdão, ganhei muito negativo...então pensei que se continuasse aberta ia ser como várias outras n todas, só ganha negativo e nada de resposta que responda a dúvida, desculpa mesmo

Comment: Como eu faço com o UTC pra pegar os horários dos locais, eu vejo tipo: UTC-2: Cidade....

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas UTC é o horário zero, à partir daí vc tem os horários que está horas a mais ou menos dele.